# How to Use Scenario Outlines to Navigate to Multiple URLs with Selenium WebDriver and C#

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#

I have searched and have not found a clear (enough for me) answer to after using Scenario Outlines to specify multiple URLs I'd like to navigate to using Selenium Webdriver and C#. How do I setup the C# to handle each URL? This is currently my steps:

```
Scenario Outline: Search
Given I Navigate to <URL>

Examples:
    | URL |
    | https://aaa.com/foo/bar/uniqueID1/en-us |
    | https://aaa.com/foo/bar/uniqueID2/en-us |
    | https://aaa.com/foo/bar/uniqueID3/en-us |
```

And this is my Step Def:

```
[Binding]
public class Search
{
    [Given(@"I Navigate to 
https://aaa\.com/foo/bar/(.*)/en-us")]
    public void GivenINavigateToHttpsAaa_FooBarEn_Us(int p0)
    {
        driver.url("https://aaa.com/foo/bar/(.*)/en-us");
    }
```

However, running this doesn't pull in each scenario from the outline as I expected. Where am I going wrong with my Step Definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you didn't put the parameter *p0* for the unique id to *drive.url()* method.

This code should work.

```
[Given(@"I Navigate to https://aaa\.com/foo/bar/(.*)/en-us")]
  public void GivenINavigateToHttpsAaa_FooBarEn_Us(int p0)
  {
    driver.url("https://aaa.com/foo/bar/" + p0 + "/en-us");
  }
```

Be careful on coding stuff when do the automation. Print it out in console or debugging helps me a lot to solve this kind of case.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me - I'm new to C# so I overlook a lot of common things - especially when the regex is generated by Visual Studio and I didn't have to work my way through it myself. Thanks again!